# How to access property of stringified JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, express, http

I have this code that sends me back an url and an error. I'm trying to access the url so I can navigate to it with router.

With this code:

```
const redirectToStripe = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cartItems.value),
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) =>
      console.log("stringied response", JSON.stringify(response))
    );

  const { url } = await response.json();
  console.log("url=", url);  <--------------Doesn't execute, no console.log() readout

  // window.location.href = url;
  // router.go(url)  <------- NEED TO FIX THIS AND UNCOMMENT;
};
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')
> at redirectToStripe

and this console.log() readout:

```
stringied response {"url":"https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1X3r92YtZfM9H"}
```

That is the url I'm trying to navigate to, but I don't know how to access it in this stringified form. How do I grab the value of "url" so I can put it in the function:

```
router.go(url)
```

The later "url" console.log() never executes because of the json error (pretty sure), but I'm guessing it's the same url as the stringified one above?

---

I also don't know why I'm getting that error or if it's even consequential and needs to be fixed because I'm already getting the url I need. Does the error have something to do with the "Content-Type" header? Did I pick the right one? Is it something else I'm doing wrong?

---

Also, this is what the backend endpoint looks like if it adds context or anything.

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  // Make an array of just our Stripe Price ID and quantities
  const lineItems = req.body.map((item) => {
    console.log("lineItems= ", item.item.priceId, item.item.quantity);
    return {
      price: item.item.priceId,
      quantity: item.item.quantity,
    };
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: "payment",
    line_items: lineItems,
    success_url: `http://localhost:8080/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:8080/`,
  });
  return res.send({ url: session.url });
});
```

---

**EDITS**

**@pope_maverick**

This code:

```
const redirectToStripe = () => {
  const response = fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(cartItems.value),
  }).then((response) => response.json());
  const {url} = response.json();
  // const { url } = await response.json();
  console.log("url=", url);
```

gets me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function

Comment: why awaiting response.json(), can you try removing the second .then statement and try consoling response? usually you should send a status code along with your response and you should validate before calling eg: if (response.status === 200) {const { url } = response; router.go(url);}

Comment: It is discouraged to mix `async`/`await` with `.then()` callbacks. If you rewrite your code to just use `async`/`await`, it most likely will resolve your issue.

Comment: @pope_maverick Check my edit. It gets me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function`

Comment: @EricAndre `response` (in `const {url} = response.json()`) is a Promise object that resolves to the value returned by the `response.json()` inside of the `then()` callback. You then try to use `.json()` on it once again. Remove the `.then((response) => response.json())` completely, and then add `await` before the other `response.json()` to unwrap the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the `response` in your last `.then` callback. So your `const response` is actually `void`.

```js
const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session",
    // [...]
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("stringied response", JSON.stringify(response))
      // ❗️ Return `response` here, or the Promise will return the returned value of `console.log` which is `void`!
      return response
    });
```

Comment: Good catch. I fixed it, but I'm still getting the `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function
    at redirectToStripe` error

Comment: You should check if the response object is an error or not. If it fails, you can't run `.json`. `if (!response.ok) { throw new Error('HTTP error! Status: {response.status}'); }`